# How to define special characters in JMeter parameterization

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I am trying to parameterize my request using CSV Data Set Config. My input includes  double quotes("), colon(:) and brackets([])
Eg: fiscal_year ":["2021",2019]"
Had tried with it, but in the actual results its passing as "fiscal_year "":[""2021""

Please share your inputs on what am i missing on the input paramter.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's due to `double quotes("), colon(:) and brackets([])`, CSV stands for [**comma**-separated values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) so JMeter treats it as a delimiter and reads everything including to the first comma.

So you might want to change the "Delimiter" to something else:

[image]

It's hard to come up with a comprehensive solution without seeing at least couple of lines from your CSV file and the way you're parameterizing the HTTP Request with [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

In case you have one entry per line in the CSV file it might be easier to go for [__StringFromFile() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile) which reads next line from the file each time it's being called. See [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) for more information.

Comment: My CSV file data is as below:                                                                                      
 fiscal_year ":["2021",2019]"
agen":["test","test1"]" . while i am using __StringFromFile() function my output is still coming as "fiscal_year "":[""2021"",2019]""". Additional double quotes are getting appended.

Comment: Any option to handle double quotes in the string?